# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE only 1 row is inserted

Tags: mysql

I have this code for importing excel date to mysql data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 

"C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/sales.csv" INTO TABLE 

db_osys.sales
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@sales_id, sales_name, @firstname, @lastname, @middlename, 

@address, @sales_class, @zip_code, @area_code, branch_code, 

@user_id, @sales_char)
```

I only need two data (`sales_name` and`branch_code`) as you can observe so I skipped all the other columns. Here's how my .csv file looks like:

[image]

The script runs fine but it only inserts 1 row. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you please point it out for the script to run properly?

**EDIT**

Here's the sales table structure:

[image]

Comment: share sales table structure

Comment: Are you using windows? If so, try \r\n at the end.

Comment: It also inserted just 1 row.

Comment: Have you tried \r on its own. Or explicitly put some random character at the end of the line, just to test. I don't use mysql or windows any more but l remember line endings being a major pita with load data infile. One line, no error.

Comment: Still no good. I've also tried filling up those empty columns with random texts but its still inserting just one row.